# How do you add launch options on the XFCE launcher?

Tags: launcher, xfce, xfce-panel

I'm trying to make a launcher script on a panel but it just shows me

`Failed to execute child process "LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8" (no such file or directory)`
with the command 
`LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8 LANG=en_CA.UTF-8 wine app.exe`

It looks like you can't really add options before the action. I have no problems running this command on a terminal but it looks like that it doesnt' work that way on a XFCE panel launcher program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XFCE launcher is NOT a shell, so it doesn't like shell tricks.

The easy way to do this is to create a bash script to do what you want, and call that script from the XFCE launcher.

The script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_ALL=en_CA.UTF-8 LANG=en_CA.UTF-8 wine app.exe
```

Be sure to `chmod +x` the script.